# What negative and positive effects random workouts might have on our body?

Tags: workout-routines

I have this list of more than 2000 different types of exercises that can be done for fitness purposes.

Say each time I go to gym (3 times a week), I randomly select 12 items from this list. Completely random.

What negative and positive effects this might have on my body?

What I'm asking is what happens if we simply get past traditional workout routines which are written by trainers and should be repeated for a while until we get new routines. I want to know this practice is just a traditional practice being around that can be changed, or is it something backed scientifically.

Answer (score 1):

There’s nothing wrong with mixing up the exercises for your routine.  Years ago, this was called the “non-routine” exercise routine.  This meant that you did not follow a formal training program.  Rather, you went to the gym and worked on whatever you felt needed improvement.  Of course, that’s going to depend on your training goal(s).

With this type of routine, the importance is placed on the individual body part that needs improvement and **not** the exercise.  Following this approach can help in preventing boredom and training plateaus since you’re constantly mixing up things.  Additionally, switching up set/rep combinations can be used to further help in reaching your goals.

Following a specific rigid program from a trainer is a typical progression for someone new to fitness training.  Again, the trainer should be designing the routine to accommodate an individual’s goals.  But, over time, and with experience, the trainee should assume responsibility for his/her goals and become less reliant on a trainer’s direction.

Comment: So, from the point of scientific analysis, there is no harm in "non-routine exercise routing" any more than there is in "supervised planned exercise routine". In both you should take care of your body, not push the boundaries to the limit of harm and injury, and etc. Am I right?

Comment: Any routine, even those provided by a trainer, are not free from possible injury.  Care should always be taken to perform the routine with correct form.

Answer (score 0):

Random workouts may or may not harm your health.. It depends on the combination. If you don't do free hand exercises before and after hard work then your muscles may get hardened nullifying the possibility of further growth. If you stretch and after that don't do jogging you will feel pain in your leg muscles later... Every rules regarding this has a logic. You can also make your own combination but that you have to understand the logic

Comment: I didn't get a clear answer here. It's all vague. Are you telling me that I should warm up before, do any random workout routine, and then cool down after? Then everything is gonna be alright? I'm OK with pain. I just want to know if it's OK to randomly create a routine for each day, a fresh routine that is more exciting and less boring, because of new activities to experience.

Comment: By the nature of randomness, saying "random workouts may or may not harm your health, it depends on the combination" is essentially equivalent to saying "random workouts will eventually harm your health". If harm is possible with some combination, eventually you'll find it.